# How to display Images on CakePHP template file (default.ctp) Using Bootstrap

Tags: php, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a Website Dashboard in CakePHP.. And i'm using bootstrap 3.0.

1) I want to display an image present in `webroot/img` in the `default.ctp` file.

2) I want that image to be displayed inside the `thumbnails( bootstrap )` div.

I used `html helper`
ie, `echo $this->Html->image('img.png', array('alt' => 'CakePHP'));` for the `source` attribute of `img` tag.

but not working..

**Edit**

This is how i have tried within bootstrap code.

```
<div class="row"
    <p><b>Target Image</b></p>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img data-src="holder.js/100%x100" src="<?php $this->Html->image('img.png', array('alt' => 'CakePHP', 'border' => '0')); ?>" />
          </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit:**
You are placing a complete image tag into an image's source. See the cookbook's HTML helper for this topic: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html

So if you replace this line:

```
<img data-src="holder.js/100%x100" src="<?php $this->Html->image('img.png', array('alt' => 'CakePHP', 'border' => '0')); ?>" />
```

With this line:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('img.png', array('alt' => 'CakePHP', 'border' => '0', 'data-src' => 'holder.js/100%x100')); ?>
```

that should do the trick.

Comment: thats what the problem is.. if i write it outside of bootstrap thumbnails div then it will display the image.. but i want that image to be displayed inside that box.. pls take a look at edited code..

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
$this->Html->image('img.png', array('alt' => 'CakePHP'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the holder script work properly the src property of the img element should not be setted.

So, a propoer solution is:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('', array('alt' => 'CakePHP', 'border' => '0', 'data-src' => 'holder.js/100%x100')); ?>
```