# Gif image is not displaying sometimes but alt text is displaying?

Tags: html, css, image, gif, loader

during page transition am using gif image to represent as 'loader' .But first 2 or 3 navigation i can see the image and rest of the transition instead of image am only able to see the "alt" text i have give with blank imagebox.

I think the image is not loading,please check my code

```
<div id="loadinggif" class="overlay"  align="center" style="display:none;">
<img src="img/gif.gif" alt="loader" height="50" width="50">
</div>
```

and when i click one page navigation am using following code

```
$('#loadinggif').css('display','block');
```

Please check my screen shots  first one is working perfectly ,second screnshots showing the exact problem am facing now.
[image]

[image]

Comment: probably because of the relative URL you're using for the image. Try using an absolute URL and see if that works.

Comment: wat i sthis absolute url?

Comment: an example absolute URL: http://example.com/img/someimg.gif

Answer (score 1):

Are your 'pages' in the same file/location? Make sure the relative path to your image is correct everywhere you use it.

Another thing would be to clear your browser cache.

If you still cannot get it to work, I would suggest inspecting it when it doesn't load, and looking at the browser's console. Depends on the browser, but most you can right click the image then 'inspect element', or something very similar.

Comment: no pages are in different location ,its MVC architecture. So how can i give relative path?

Comment: I can't say for sure. If you are using a framework it most likely has a built in way for handling links and assets.

Comment: but please tell me...some way to fix this

Comment: What MVC architecture are you using?

Comment: I'm not familiar with CakePHP, but it looks like it has a image() method for generating image links. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416246/how-to-display-images-on-cakephp-template-file-default-ctp-using-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Try to fully qualify the image. Such as https://mywebsite.com/img/spinner.gif. Now, if that fails, do not give up on life, there is still hope! What I normally do, is have a div with a css/Less class that has the image in it. That way, the image is loading through the dom, and to hide n show, simply hide n show the dom element with that specific class.

Let me know if that works.

Cheers M8.